# Проблема с JOIN

Tags: php, join, sql, mysql

Что не так с запросом?

```
SELECT p.*,k.name FROM posts AS p LEFT JOIN `post-keywords` AS pk ON p.id = pk.id_post 
LEFT JOIN keywords AS k ON pk.id_keyword = p.id ORDER BY p.id DESC LIMIT :num,:count
```

Почему-то сервер возвращает k.name = NULL

[image]

вот что говорит сервер:

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["title"]=>
    string(28) "Всё о интернете"
    ["text"]=>
    string(41) "Тут просто сама статья"
    ["date"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["name"]=>
    NULL
  }
  [1]=>
  array(5) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["title"]=>
    string(16) "Интернет"
    ["text"]=>
    string(32) "Текст текст текст"
    ["date"]=>
    string(10) "1371186330"
    ["name"]=>
    NULL
  }
  [2]=>
  array(5) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["title"]=>
    string(16) "Интернет"
    ["text"]=>
    string(32) "Текст текст текст"
    ["date"]=>
    string(10) "1371186330"
    ["name"]=>
    NULL
  }
  [3]=>
  array(5) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["title"]=>
    string(16) "Интернет"
    ["text"]=>
    string(32) "Текст текст текст"
    ["date"]=>
    string(10) "1371186330"
    ["name"]=>
    NULL
  }
  [4]=>
  array(5) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["title"]=>
    string(16) "Интернет"
    ["text"]=>
    string(32) "Текст текст текст"
    ["date"]=>
    string(10) "1371186330"
    ["name"]=>
    NULL
  }
  [5]=>
  array(5) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["title"]=>
    string(16) "Интернет"
    ["text"]=>
    string(32) "Текст текст текст"
    ["date"]=>
    string(10) "1371186330"
    ["name"]=>
    NULL
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот тут у вас опечатка:

> LEFT JOIN keywords AS k ON pk.id_keyword = **p**.id

по идеи надо:

```
SELECT p.*,k.name FROM posts AS p LEFT JOIN `post-keywords` AS pk ON p.id = pk.id_post 
LEFT JOIN keywords AS k ON pk.id_keyword = k.id ORDER BY p.id DESC LIMIT :num,:count
```